# Does wp_nav_menu use the gettext filter?

Tags: menus, translation

I'm working on some multilingual code in a theme, and I was wondering if `wp_nav_menu` uses the `gettext` filter internally (i.e. same functionality as `__()` and `_e()`.)

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of your question is not entirely clear, but no, there are no gettext calls inside [`wp_nav_menu`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/). There is no reason for that, as this function is not outputting any strings itself, just passing on what it gets.